# Wordpress gives 404 on any page that doesn't belong to it

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a website on which wordpress is installed and I can't manage to create normal php files. They all give me 404.

Wordpress works fine, everything is ok. htaccess looks good also, but when I try to create a php file, eg /example-dir/simple-file.php, and try to access it, instead of displaying my page (which has only an echo inside), it displays a 404.

Any tips how to deactivate this peculiar behavior? I tried disabling all the plugins, but didn't help.

The htaccess looks like this:

> `RewriteEngine On
>
>   RewriteBase /
>
>   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
>
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
>   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`

Edit:
It behaves like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` wouldn't be present.
Another interesting observation is that it does this only for the php files. If I create test.txt, it works fine.

Comment: probably in a .htaccess rewrite, you've forgotten the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`.

Comment: Nope, the htaccess is good. I updated the question

Comment: 1. try disabling `.htaccess` (rename it) and see if there is any difference  2. try to access a test php file at the root level

Comment: 1. If I disable `.htaccess` it gives 500 everywhere on the site :| 2. I tried to place a php file in the root level also, same thing (i tried at different levels)

Comment: @AdiUlici You can't directly access any php file in WordPress.

Comment: WordPress is installed in my root directory and I can't access any php file that doesn't belong to wordpress, like /example.php, even though it's an empty file.

Comment: @rikesh: yes, you can. that's the point of the `-f` and `-d` rules in a standard WP .htaccess install. "any file or directory which REALLY exists, allow direct access".

Comment: Adi - you may need to check your actual domain URL against what is set in WP for the "Home" and "Site URL" - see http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: @Raad - it was one of the first things I checked. They're ok.

Comment: @Rikesh - I did this for other wordpress sites and it worked just fine..

Comment: Adi - I think your best approach is to strip the site back to nothing and start again. Move everything in root into a subfolder, so you have no .htaccess or anything, make test html + php pages and see how the site behaves. It seems like something is interfering with normal behaviour, e.g. IIS or apache config.